# Job shows up in crontab -l but not in /etc/crontab

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

There is a certain job that shows up when I do

```
$ crontab -l
```

and I can verify that this is also running.
However, the job is not listed in `/etc/crontab`.

Say the job is /somedir/somefile
I can't seem to find where it is specified for cron

```
$ find /var/ -path *cron*  -exec grep somefile {} \; 2>e
$ find /etc/ -path *cron*  -exec grep somefile {} \; 2>e
```

don't show up anything.

If I do `crontab -e` and delete the line, the job still runs and /etc/crontab remains unchanged (since it didn't have the line in the first place!)

I am a regular user (non admin), and some of the paths in /var and /etc are inaccessible for me (that's why I do 2>e to redirect the permission denied errors). However, the con job command for this file should be accessible since I can edit it in `crontab -e`.

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 2):

The crontab you see in `/etc/crontab` is a system-wide crontab which is run as and therefore only editable by root.

When using the `crontab` command to create a user's crontab, new crontabs are placed into `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` and the file's name is the user who owns the crontab.